# Load HTML page after chrome.tabs.onCreated

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to load a static HTML file after I have opened a new tab. This code will act as a Chrome extension. I am stuck in an infinite loop and don't know how to proceed.

Here is my manifest.json:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "Getting started example",
  "description": "This extension shows a Google Image search result for the current page",
  "version": "1.0",

  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html",
    "default_title": "Click here!"
  },

  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
  },

  "permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "https://ajax.googleapis.com/"
  ]
}
```

Here is my background.js (chrome.tabs.create will result in an obvious endless loop):

```
chrome.tabs.onCreated.addListener(function(tab) {
//    INSERT HTML HERE
//    chrome.tabs.create({url: chrome.extension.getURL('mypage.html')});
});
```

How can I achieve this? Do I have to dynamically create the HTML in JavaScript? Or can I load a static HTML file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chrome extensions have an explicit option in the manifest for replacing certain pages, [chrome_url_overrides](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/override).

For example:

```
"chrome_url_overrides": {
   "newtab": "mypage.html"
},
```